# How to stop form from sending email more times after initial success.

Tags: php, xhtml

**Can someone please show me example code or specify what i am doing wrong as solutions below have not yielded much luck for me :(**
I am working on a contact form which uses jquery and php to validate and send email respectively. The form works fine until the point after the user successfully submits the form. Once the form has been submitted, a success message is successfully displayed on the same page however, upon referesh the page sends another email, thus if I do countless refreshes, I would get countless mails in my box.

```
//handler.php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    if(!isset($hasError)) {
        $body = "Name: $name \n\nEmail: $email \n\nEnquiry: $enquiry";
        $headers = 'From: My Site <'.$emailTo.'>' . "\r\n" . 'Reply-To: ' . $email;

        mail($emailTo, $subject, $body, $headers);
        $emailSent = true;
        header("location: ../about/?action=sent");
        exit();
}   

//index.php
var_dump($_GET);
<?php if(isset($hasError)) { ?> 
    <p class="error">Please make sure you have filled all fields with valid information. Thank you.</p>
<?php } ?>                        
<?php if(isset($emailSent) && $emailSent == true) { ?>
    <p><strong>Your enquiry was sent successfully.</strong></p>
    <p>Thank you for your enquiry! Your email was successfully sent and we will be in touch with you promptly.</p>
<?php }; ?>                       
<form id="contactform" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Enquiry form</legend>
        <label for="name">Name:</label><input type="text" size="50" name="name" id="name" value="" class="required" />
        <label for="email">Email:</label><input type="text" size="50" name="email" id="email" value="" class="required email" />
        <label for="enquiry">Enquiry:</label><textarea rows="5" cols="20" name="enquiry" id="enquiry" class="required"></textarea>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit enquiry" class="curved-btn"></input>
        <input type="hidden" id="form-id" name="form-id" value="general"></input>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Use a proper url in `header('Location: ../about')` (you can't use relative paths)

Comment: i did but still the same problem

Comment: Use the "post redirect" method. POST to the mail-sending script, then redirect to another page. That makes the refresh affect the "other page", not the page you POSTed to.

Comment: thanks but i'm not sure i understand you?

Answer (score 1):

You should use the [post/redirect/get](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) pattern here.

Using this pattern advocates sending a redirect as a response from your form handling page, and as a result subsequent refreshes will not trigger these actions more than once.

From the documentation:

> ...instead of returning a web page directly, the POST operation returns
>   a redirection command.

In pseudo-code, your handler page should have something like:

- Whatever initial handling code you have
- Send Email
- header("Location: /someotherpage");
- exit();

Comment: thank you, the articles makes sense however, is it possible to see a sample?

Comment: i have editted my question to include the page that handles the validation and send email. Please see above. Now, no message is displayed and secondly more than page on the site uses the handler page but the way the code is now, it would always return to the redirect. Sorry if i am asking something really obvious but i am a bit new to this

Comment: To be fair, I believe I've answered your original question and if you'd like full code solutions, you should post another question. I recently read a comment that said something along the lines of Stack isn't intended / designed for these question->answer->update->answer style responses. If you post another one with more specific code I'd be happy to take a look. Cheers,

Comment: hey man, i have done as requested, please see here for new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6865474/form-redirection-problem

Answer (score 0):

You need to properly redirect after the email is sent.  I've been using the following code for years as part of a utility class.  Unfortunately it's been copied and re-posted numerous times on the net, so I have no idea who actually created it.

```
// func: redirect($to,$code=307)
// spec: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html
// 301 Moved Permanently - Forget the old page existed
// 302 Found - Use the same method (GET/POST) to request the specified page.
// 303 See Other - Use GET to request the specified page. Use this to redirct after a POST.
// 307 Temporary Redirect - Good for response to POST.
// redirect('/')
// redirect("/my/page")
// redirect("http://www.foo.bar/page.htm",303)
// redirect("./index.php",307)
public function redirect($to,$code=307) {
    $location = null;
    $sn = $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'];
    $cp = dirname($sn);
    if (substr($to,0,4)=='http') $location = $to; // Absolute URL
    else {
        $schema = $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT']=='443'?'https':'http';
        $host = strlen($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'])?$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']:$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
        if (substr($to,0,1)=='/') $location = "$schema://$host$to";
        elseif (substr($to,0,1)=='.') {
            $location = "$schema://$host/";
            $pu = parse_url($to);
            $cd = dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']).'/';
            $np = realpath($cd.$pu['path']);
            $np = str_replace($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'],'',$np);
            $location.= $np;
            if ((isset($pu['query'])) && (strlen($pu['query'])>0)) $location.= '?'.$pu['query'];
        }
    }

    $hs = headers_sent();
    if ($hs==false) {
        if ($code==301) header("301 Moved Permanently HTTP/1.1"); // Convert to GET
        elseif ($code==302) header("302 Found HTTP/1.1"); // Conform re-POST
        elseif ($code==303) header("303 See Other HTTP/1.1"); // dont cache, always use GET
        elseif ($code==304) header("304 Not Modified HTTP/1.1"); // use cache
        elseif ($code==305) header("305 Use Proxy HTTP/1.1");
        elseif ($code==306) header("306 Not Used HTTP/1.1");
        elseif ($code==307) header("307 Temorary Redirect HTTP/1.1");
        else trigger_error("Unhandled redirect() HTTP Code: $code",E_USER_ERROR);
        header("Location: $location");
        header('Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
    }
    elseif (($hs==true) || ($code==302) || ($code==303)) {
        // todo: draw some javascript to redirect
        $cover_div_style = 'background-color: #ccc; height: 100%; left: 0px; position: absolute; top: 0px; width: 100%;';
        echo "<div style='$cover_div_style'>\n";
        $link_div_style = 'background-color: #fff; border: 2px solid #f00; left: 0px; margin: 5px; padding: 3px; ';
        $link_div_style.= 'position: absolute; text-align: center; top: 0px; width: 95%; z-index: 99;';
        echo "<div style='$link_div_style'>\n";
        echo "<p>Please See: <a href='$to'>".htmlspecialchars($location)."</a></p>\n";
        echo "</div>\n</div>\n";
    }
    exit(0);
}
```

Comment: Thanks George, but this seems a bit too much for what i am tryong to achieve. All i want is to redirect to display appropraite message and redirect to the respective page..

Comment: What is header("location: ../about"); is that the same page index.php?

Comment: Yes it is, the thing is i have used folders to group my files. so in the about folder, there is a file called index.php

Comment: Ok, yeah that's fine.  If you want a quick fix, for the header call do something like this: `header("location: ../about/?action=sent")` and then at the top of about/index.php check the `$_GET` array to see if action is set.  Then add a condition to `if(isset($_POST['submit']))` that check to see if action does not equal 'sent'.  Then you can refresh the page all you want.

Comment: If that works for you, please accept the answer to close off.

Comment: It is almost there George P. :) Please see updated code, i did a var_dump on my index page and that shows me sent but i'm a bit confused to where this if(isset($_POST['submit'])) goes as i am already doing that in my handler.php. After i have been redirected though, i no longer see my success message..